# Are the "Small Medium" books set before, after, or during the "Threadbare" books?

Tags: threadbare, small-medium

Andrew Seiple released [a LitRPG trilogy following an animated teddy bear named Threadbare](https://www.goodreads.com/series/233241-threadbare) set in a world whose physical laws match an MMORPG. His second trilogy, *[Small Medium](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/43243242-small-medium)* is set in an extremely similar world, and also features toy golems, although some characters are "Players", who are implied to be people from our world playing the game (noted to generally be sociopaths by the residents of the world, prone to killing everything, stealing your stuff, and then trying to sell it back to you). Seiple has indicated that it is the same world, "World of Generica Online", in both trilogies, but I haven't found any reference for whether they're set in the same time period. I'm sure there are references I'm not noticing yet, but I figured I'd put it out to the hivemind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked the author. Apparently it's shortly afterwards.

> **Q. Is the "Small Medium" trilogy set before or after the "Threadbare" trilogy?**
>
> **@AndrewSeiple** - *Small Medium is set about a year after the Threadbare trilogy.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Via Twitter](https://twitter.com/AndrewSeiple/status/1166769545459175424)</sup></sub>

Comment: That gives a more definitive timeline than my answer.

Answer (score 3):

### It's set after the *Threadbare* series

There is a reference in the second book, *Small Medium: At Large*, to Cylvania being open to visit, where it was closed off to the world during the *Threadbare* series.

> “It’s a little different in Cylvania,” Renny whispered from her pack. But he was loud enough for the Wizaard to hear.

And later, it's established that Graves, a character in the *Threadbare* books, now holds a leadership position.

> “No. The kingdom used to control the royal academy, but it got dissolved after the war. Now the official council arcanist is Mister Graves. He’s not a Wizard, but he helps people get the arcane training they need. And there’s plenty of Wizards around to take apprentices and teach whomever they want.”

Graves was a character introduced in the second book as a necromancer turned soldier in Cylvania's army who later allies with Threadbare and his crew.